# Convert H264 encoded video to MJPEG

Tags: h.264, video-encoding, mjpeg

I am having an issue converting some H264 encoded video to MJPEG format (contained in AVI), the video is a single video track and has no audio.

I have tried using `avconv` with the following command `avconv -i test_5.mp4 -vcodec mjpeg -q 1 -r 30 out.avi`, which results in a video which plays back far too fast.

I have also tried using Handbrake, however this produced an unplayable video.

The H264 video is captured with the `raspivid` utility on the Raspberry Pi at 30 FPS.

Comment: Use the ffmpeg tag and use the ffmpeg command line options for the best support. Libav is mainly used by people integrating multimedia functionality and avconv is ignored, whereas the ffmpeg command line community is large and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get it done using ffmpeg instead of avconv (libav), you must download a ffmpeg binary package from [here](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) or compile yourself from sources, then check out this [howto](http://www.itbroadcastanddigitalcinema.com/ffmpeg_howto.html#Encoding_MJPEG_in_Highest_Quality)